# How can I bin items <1 as 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am testing the code below (thanks Andy L.)

```
bins = [0, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25, 2.5, 2.75, 3, 3.25, 3.5, 3.75, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5, 5.25, 5.5, 5.75, 6, 6.25, 6.5, 6.75, 7, 7.25, 7.5, 7.75, 8, 8.25, 8.5, 8.75, 9, 9.25, 9.5, 9.75, 10, np.inf]
labels = ['0', '1', '1.25', '1.5', '1.75', '2', '2.25', '2.5', '2.75', '3', '3.25', '3.5', '3.75', '4', '4.25', '4.5', '4.75', '5', '5.25', '5.5', '5.75', '6', '6.25', '6.5', '6.75', '7', '7.25', '7.5', '7.75', '8', '8.25', '8.5', '8.75', '9', '9.25', '9.5', '9.75', '10']

dataset['RatingScore'] = pd.cut(dataset['Rating'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
```

It works just like I want it to, except for values that are <1 in the 'Rating' field.  I would like to capture everything <1, including any negative numbers, and sweep all of it into a bin labeled 0.  I thought the leading 0 in 'bins' and 'labels' would handle this scenario, but it doesn't.

Comment: this question is much clearer than your comment in the other question and @ALollz answer is excellent. Upvoted both question and answer :) +1

Comment: Yeah, it took me a little while to understand what the real issue was.  Now it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your left edge to be `-np.inf` as a catch-all for anything below 1 (similar to your right edge), or since the only thing not binned will be negative numbers you could `.fillna`

```
#bins = [0, 1, 1.25, 1.5 ..., np.inf]
df['RatingScore'] = pd.cut(df['rating'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True).fillna(labels[0])

#bins = [-np.inf, 1, 1.25, 1.5, ..., np.inf]
df['RatingScore'] = pd.cut(df['rating'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'rating': np.random.normal(0, 10, 5)})

bins = [-np.inf, 1, 5, 9, np.inf]
labels = ['0', '1', '5', '9']

df['RatingScore'] = pd.cut(df['rating'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=True)
#          rating RatingScore
#0 -10.856306           0
#1   9.973454           9
#2   2.829785           1
#3 -15.062947           0
#4  -5.786003           0
```